# How to check config setting in custom service class with dependency injection?

Tags: 8, configuration, services, dependency-injection

In a custom Service class, I need to check a config setting.

I'm able to do this using `\Drupal::config(static::SETTINGS)` as documented here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms

but Coder complains:

> **WARNING** | `\Drupal` calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead

What service should I inject here?

I only need to see the immutable config value, I don't think I need a `ConfigFactory`.

More info:

When I try to inject the `ConfigFactoryInterface`, using the pattern I have followed for many other services, I get this error:

> Error: Call to undefined method `Drupal\my_custom_module\Api\DataPartner::config()` in `Drupal\my_custom_module\Api\DataPartner->hasDebugPermission()`

The code in the `hasDebugPermission()` method looks like this:

```php
  /**
   * Private function to control whether displaying debug info is permitted.
   *
   * @return bool
   *   TRUE if debugging is permitted for current user in current environment.
   */
  private function hasDebugPermission() {
    $config = $this->config(static::SETTINGS);
    $result = DATA_PARTNER_FORMS_DEBUG
      && $config->get('display_debugging_info')
      && $this->account->hasPermission('debug forms');
    return $result;
  }
```

And I have declared `static::SETTINGS` like this:

```php
  /**
   * Config settings.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  private const SETTINGS = 'my_custom_module.settings';
```

The call to `$this->account->hasPermission()` works fine after injecting `\Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface`, but the call to `$this->config('my_custom_module.settings')->get('display_debugging_info')` does not work after injecting `\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you inject `config.factory` and then you need to use:

```
$this->config
  ->get('my_custom_module.settings')
  ->get('display_debugging_info');
```

You can see that [Drupal::config()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Aconfig/8.2.x) is:

```
public static function config($name) {
  return static::getContainer()
    ->get('config.factory')
    ->get($name);
}
```

So after injecting your service, the equivalent of `\Drupal::config('my_custom_module.settings')` is:

```
$this->config->get('my_custom_module.settings');
```

Comment: Perfect answer! You even ended on exactly the line where I forgot the `->get` after `$this->config`. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, the bug in my code came straight from Drupal community documentation: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms

Comment: @hotwebmatter – Which lines in the docs exactly are you referring to? We should update the docs then. But note, that the ConfigFormBase already comes with the config factory pre-injected you then in a custom service class need to inject yourself. See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.9.3/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/ConfigFormBase.php#L29

Comment: Also note that the *ConfigFormBase* class uses the *ConfigFormBaseTrait* which defines a method [config()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21ConfigFormBaseTrait.php/function/ConfigFormBaseTrait%3A%3Aconfig/8.2.x) which is not the same as simply naming your injected config factory service `$config`. You can see that method is a shortcut to the above, it's similar to calling `\Drupal::config()`.

Comment: @leymannx I fixed the line in the docs: https://www.drupal.org/node/2206607/revisions/view/11783167/12036988

Comment: The docs were actually correct to begin with. As I tried to explain in the comment, *ConfigFormBase* has a `config()` method.

Comment: @sonfd Thank you, that makes sense. This method works for me in my config form; it just isn't available in my custom service class because that class does not inherit the methods from ConfigFormBase. I'll change it back. **EDIT:** Never mind, I see you beat me to it. Thanks again!